# Disable or redirect keyboard input made to spawned subprocesses

Tags: c#, process

I have the calculator that comes with Windows. I wrote a C# application to launch it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "Calc";
        proc.Start();
    }
}
```

I am interested in whether I can suppress key input to the subprocess. For example, in calculator you can just hit the number keys to enter input.

Is it possible to disable those keys from doing anything through my application? Or, is it possible to force all input to the calculator to go through my application first?

For example, suppose I want to make it so that pressing the number 5 in the calculator doesn't do anything if the calculator was launched using my application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can redirect the standard input stream, which will prevent the user from entering text to the console window directly. Your program can write to the `Process.StandardInput` (which is a `TextWriter`) to send input to the process.

Change your click handler to this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "Calc";
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    _process.Exited += (sender1, e1) => process.Dispose();
    proc.Start();
}
```

Three notes:

- You obviously need to retain a reference to the `Process` instance, or at least its `StandardInput` object, if you want to actually write to its input stream.
- You must set `UseShellExecute` to false for redirection to work, which disables some of the automatic behavior of the `Process` class (e.g. specifying a file instead of executable). This may or may not be an issue in your specific scenario.
- It is best to dispose the `Process` object once the process has ended. I include a couple of lines in the example above to address this (enable raising events, and then handling the `Exited` event by disposing the `Process` object)